# full process of Joining 2 diffrent filed from a table and creating new filed in spark sql

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is dataframe i created from json file in spark (scala)

|   A    |    B   |    C  |

|   1    |    a   |    x  |

|   2    |    b   |    x  |

now i want the following result as my final result,

|   A    |    B   |    C  |    D  |

|   1    |    a   |    x  |  1ax  |

|   2    |    b   |    y  |  2bx  |
 where ABC and ABCD is a header of json dataset, 1 and 2 are data in that heard respectively . and i want to join or concatenate to get header D with data as 1ax and 2by.
any help ??

Comment: @zero323 its different

Comment: If it is different please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [mcve] and edit this question accordingly.

Comment: @zero323 sir i guess my question is clear. i wanted to create a new header as D. and data for my header D should be mapped by using join or concatenate function. sry if it wasnt clear. i am new to it

Comment: No reason to apologize. Instead just provide example input (ascii table is not a one), expected output and your attempts so far. In other words [_pretend you're talking to a busy colleague_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For now it looks like you want concatenate columns what is an *exact* duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @zero323 thank u sir .. i was clear does the same rule applies if we need to concatenate using 3 column ??